# REST not returning all the values in my DB

Tags: java, mysql, rest

Hello all i am not getting all the values of the in the db while returning a rest reponse.

Below is my DAO

```
public class BooksDAO {

public List<Book> getAllBooks() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    List<Book> arrBook = null;
    Book e = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    JdbcRowSet rowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createJdbcRowSet();
    rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books");
    rowSet.setUsername("xxxx");
    rowSet.setPassword("xxxx");
    rowSet.setCommand("select * from books.library");
    rowSet.execute();

    while (rowSet.next()) {

        e = new Book(rowSet.getInt(1), rowSet.getString(2), rowSet.getString(3), rowSet.getString(4));
        arrBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
        arrBook.add(e);

    }

    return arrBook;

}
```

Below is my Service

```
public class BookService {

BooksDAO booksDao = new BooksDAO();

//private Map<Integer, Book> books = Database.getBooks();

/*public BookService() {
    books.put(1, new Book(1, "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", "$28", "Mark Twain"));
    books.put(2, new Book(2, "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes", "$17", "Arthur Conan Doyle"));
}*/

public List<Book> getAllBooks() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return new ArrayList<Book>(booksDao.getAllBooks());

}
```

Below is my resource

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8",MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8"})
public Response getBooks(@QueryParam("format") String format) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity((new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(bookService.getAllBooks()) {
    })).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "XML".equalsIgnoreCase(format)
            ? MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=UTF-8" : MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8").build();

}
```

I am getting the below REST response

```
[
  {
    "author": "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    "id": 2,
    "links": [],
    "name": "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes",
    "price": "$17"
  }
]
```

It is returning the last one but not the whole list...

Where did I do the mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `BookDao#getAllBooks` method implementation, your are reconstructing the `ArrayList` holding your results for each element within the same loop traversing your `ResultSet`:

```java
while (rowSet.next()) {
  e = new Book(rowSet.getInt(1), rowSet.getString(2), rowSet.getString(3),rowSet.getString(4));
  arrBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
  arrBook.add(e);
}
```

The list should be initialized once before looping through the `ResultSet` elements:

```java
arrBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
while (rowSet.next()) {
  e = new Book(rowSet.getInt(1), rowSet.getString(2), rowSet.getString(3),rowSet.getString(4));
  arrBook.add(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your code as follows :

```
arrBook = new ArrayList<Book>();                

while (rowSet.next()) {
        e = new Book(rowSet.getInt(1), rowSet.getString(2), rowSet.getString(3), rowSet.getString(4));
        arrBook.add(e);
    }
```

You are initializing your arrBook for every book. This makes a new arraylist and discards the data you already added. Try initializing that arrBook arraylist outside your while loop.